# Pasar una función como parámetro en otra función

Tags: c++

Estoy intentado pasar una función como parámetro en otra función pero me da problemas. Al intentarlo no me deja ponerle parámetros dentro de la función. ¿Es posible hacer esto?

```
void drawresult(int (*func) ()) {
    printf("2 + 2 = %i ", func(2, 2));
}

int suma(int n1, int n2) {
    return n1 + n2;
}


int main() {
    drawresult(suma);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres que la función recibida como parámetro reciba a su vez parámetros, debes declararlo como parte del tipo de `func`, así:

```
void drawresult(int (*func) (int, int)) {
...
}
```

No es necesario nombrar los parámetros de `func`, pero sí declarar sus tipos.

Por cierto que si compilas con un compilador de C en lugar de C++, el dejarlo como lo tenías no se considera un error (aunque puede causar problelmas inesperados en tiempo de ejecución si la función que pasas como parámetro no tiene el número y tipo de parámetros apropiado).

Answer (score 3):

La forma estándar de hacer esto en C++ es con functores. Revisa [std::function](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

De esta forma podrías hacer:

```
void drawresult (std::function<int(int,int)>& f)
{
    std::cout << "suma: " << f (2,2) << std::endl;
}
```

La sintáxis que falta en el link es `[](parametros) -> retorno {cuerpo}` cuando llamas a la funcion y definis el functor dentro de la llamada. Por ejemplo:

```
drawresult (
    [] (int, int) -> int
    {
        // lo mismo que en la funxion suma o lo que sea
        // directo sobre la llamada a drawresult
    }
);
```

Cabe destacar que en C++, siempre que la biblioteca estándar define una solución estándar, lo mejor es no ponernos a escribir soluciones alternativas.